# MyPy stub for the faker library

Tags: python, mypy

I am using faker 12.3.3 in my Python project and want to use MyPy as part of my code quality checks.

I get the following error

```
error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "faker"
```

I have looked on [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/tree/master/stubs) but there are no stubs shown there.

I am guessing that I would have to write a stub file for the particular faker classes I am using?

I am using PyEnv to run various versions of Python so am not sure where such a stub, if I was to write it, would be installed.

Another option is to tell MyPy to ignore the faker class which feels like a cop out.
There are a number of widely used Python libraries that seem to trip up MyPy so knowing how best to deal with these issues would be a big boost.

Comment: The latest version appears to have type hints. It was added in [October 2021](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/commit/9a382ed237ef6ac40eb272703eb3b6ce0546ad0f).